# Cómo abrir abrir y comenzar DatePickerDialog con una fecha específica? (No la fecha actual)

Tags: android-studio, datepicker

Tengo 2 edittext, el primer edittext abre un DatePickerDialog mostrando la fecha actual, con el método onDataSet del selector puedo seleccionar una fecha dentro del calendario, el problema está en que necesito que el segundo edittext empiece "marcando" con la fecha que fué seleccionada en el primer edittext. ¿Es posible hacerlo?

Les dejo parte de mi código:

```
 /******* VARIABLES GLOBALES *****/

final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

final Calendar myCalendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

private int pYearFI, pYearFF;
private int pMonthFI, pMonthFF;
private int pDayFI, pDayFF;
private int GuardarAño, GuardarMes, GuardarDia;

String fecha_inicio_guardada;

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener selector_fecha_inicio,selector_fecha_fin;

DatePickerDialog dialog_fecha_inicio, dialog_fecha_fin;

/****** dentro del onCreate() *****/

et_fecha_inicio_del_evento_nuevo_responsable = (EditText) 
findViewById(R.id.et_nuevo_responsable_fecha_inicio_evento_formulario_patrocinio_supervisor);


selector_fecha_inicio = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month,
                              int day) {



                pYearFI = year;
                pMonthFI = month;
                pDayFI = day;


                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, pYearFI);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,pMonthFI);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,pDayFI);


                updateLabelFechaInicio();



            } /**** Fin del método onDataSet ****/

    }; /*********** Fin del método setOnClickListener ***********/


        dialog_fecha_inicio = new DatePickerDialog(this, selector_fecha_inicio, pYearFI,
                pMonthFI, pDayFI);


        dialog_fecha_inicio.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime());



        et_fecha_inicio_del_evento_nuevo_responsable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog_fecha_inicio.show();

            } /**** Fin del método onClick ****/


        }); /*********** Fin del método setOnClickListener ***********/



      et_fecha_fin_del_evento_nuevo_responsable = (EditText) 
      findViewById(R.id.et_nuevo_responsable_fecha_fin_evento_formulario_patrocinio);

      selector_fecha_fin = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {



            pYearFF = year;
            pMonthFF = monthOfYear;
            pDayFF = dayOfMonth;


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pYearFF= myCalendar2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            myCalendar2.set(Calendar.MONTH,pMonthFF);
            myCalendar2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,pDayFF);

            updateLabelFechaFin();



        } /**** Fin del método onDataSet ****/

    }; /*********** Fin del método setOnClickListener ***********/
```

//LE PASO COMO PARÁMETROS: EL AÑO DE LA FECHA_DE_INCIO, EL MES DE LA FECHA_DE_INICIO, EL DIA DE LA FECHA_DE INICIO DEL PRIMER EDITTEXT PORQUE QUIERO QUE EL datepickerdialog COMIENCE EN LA FECHA QUE YO COMO USUARIO SELECCIONÉ DEL del DPDialog.

```
       dialog_fecha_fin = new DatePickerDialog(this, selector_fecha_fin, pYearFI, pMonthFI, pDayFI);
```

//A ESTA FECHA SELECCIONADA DEBERÍA PASARLA A MILISEGUNDOS PARA QUE: AL ABRIR EL DatePickerDialog EL MARCADOR ESTÉ POSICIONADO EN LA FECHA QUE SELECCIONE DEL PRIMER EDITTEXT, Y QUE ADEMÁS LAS FECHAS ANTERIORES A LA FECHA SELECCIONADA ESTÉN DESHABILITADAS (sin embargo esto no funciona, ni siquiera me posiciona en la fecha actual, sino en una fecha muy antigua (año 1900))

```
  dialog_fecha_fin.getDatePicker().setMinDate(ConvertirFechaEnMilisegundos(pDayFI,pMonthFI,pYearFI));


        et_fecha_fin_del_evento_nuevo_responsable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             dialog_fecha_fin.show();



             }

        });




   /******* FUERA DEL onCreate()*******/
```

//CON ESTA FUNCIÓN ES POSIBLE CONVERTIR UNA FECHA EN MILISEGUNDOS PARA LUEGO USARLA EN EL MÉTODO setMinDate(long)

```
    public static long ConvertirFechaEnMilisegundos(int day, int month, int year) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, month, day);
    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

//CON ESTA FUNCIÓN LO QUE HAGO ES PASAR LA FECHA EN UN FORMATO MAS SIMPLE (simpleFormat) a cadena.

```
   private void updateLabelFechaInicio() {

    String myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"; //In which you need put here

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

    fecha_inicio_guardada = sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime());

    et_fecha_inicio_del_evento_nuevo_responsable.setText(fecha_inicio_guardada);

} /******************** FIN DE LA FUNCIÓN updateLabelFechaInicio() *******************/
```

//ESTA FUNCIÓN CUMPLE EL MISMO ROL QUE LA ANTERIOR

```
    private void updateLabelFechaFin() {

    String myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"; //In which you need put here

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

    String fecha_fin_guardada = sdf.format(myCalendar2.getTime());

    et_fecha_fin_del_evento_nuevo_responsable.setText(fecha_fin_guardada);

} /******************** FIN DE LA FUNCIÓN updateLabelFechaFin() *******************/
```

Answer (score 0):

**Para colocar una fecha por defecto seria de la siguiente manera.**

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse("1988/01/01");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    mYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth.concat("/").concat((monthOfYear + 1)).concat("/").concat(year));

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: es posible almacenar los valores que trae por defecto el método void onDataSet? es decir, almacenar en variables los parámetros de year, monthOfYear y dayOfMonth para usarlos en el DatePickerDialog del otro EditText? lo eh intentado y es que si los valores de las variables son nulas o cero.